# How can I extrude a regular, grid-based 2D shape to 3D?

Tags: opengl, 3d

I have a list of vertex coordinates which encircle several 2D areas. Orthogonal lines only, but not necessarily convex areas... similar to PCB traces of conductive copper areas. I want to draw them like solid objects in 3D using OpenGL, but I'm still very new to 3D and struggling.

Please point me how to do this. I've managed to draw the outline only using `GL_LINE_STRIP`, but when I try `GL_QUAD_STRIP` or `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, the list of coordinates is not properly ordered for triangle strip and the fact the areas are not convex prevent me from doing a simple triangular tessellation.

These are the 2D shapes:

[image: Illustration]

I'd like to render them like this:

[image]

Comment: You're right, my heading is a bit misleading, I'm sorry. I'm basically trying to add a third dimension to a 2D area outline. I have the 2D coordinates for the outline, and would like it to look like this:

http://img4.yeggi.com/images_q/414287/tetris-blocks

Answer (score 1):

There are three parts to solving this;

1. tessellating the  concave polygons into triangles (opengl
   cannot draw concave polys). This will be the 'top' surface
2. displacing (extruding) the the set of triangles along an appropriate
   vector, this will become the 'bottom' surface
3. generating the 'sides' of the volume, by joining up the
   *outside* edges of top & bottom surfaces

### Part 1 - Tessellation of top surface

The simplest answer for concave polygon tessellation with no holes is EAR clipping.

[image]

{v3,v0,v1} & {v1,v2,v3} are ears, {v0,v1,v2} is not an ear (v3 lies inside {v0,v1,v2}), {v2,v3,v0) is not an ear (the interior angle at v3 is > π)  .
An EAR of a polygon is a triangle formed by three consecutive vertices V0, V1 and V2 for which V1 is a convex vertex (the interior angle at the vertex is smaller than π radians), the line segment from Vi0 to Vi2 lies completely inside the polygon, and no vertices of the polygon are contained in the triangle other than the three vertices of the triangle. A polygon of 4 or more vertices always has an ear. So our approach is to find an ear, chop it off, repeat until there is only one ear left (triangle);

```
do until num vertices of P is 3
    find an ear vq,vr,vs
    add vq,vr,vs to list of triangles
    remove vr from polygon
end do
add last 3 vertices to triangle list
```

Draw this list as a GL_TRIANGLE_LIST

There are more efficient approaches to polygon triangulation(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation), but the ear method is by far the simplest.

### Part 2 - Generate bottom surface

Copy all the vertices found in part one and add your extrusion vector to each of them. This becomes your 'bottom' surface.
The extrusion vector is a vector (typically) at right angles to your initial polygon. The length of the extrusion vector  depends on how long your extrusion needs to be.

### Part 3 - Generate sides of extrusion

Take each edge of your original concave polygon. Add the extrusion vector to the edge's two end points. This generates 4 points (2 original end points and 2 'extruded' end points) These form a rectangle*, which will be one of the sides of the extrusion. These can be drawn as GL_QUADS or GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP depending on order.

*assuming a right angle extrusion vector.

Comment: I think you are either misunderstanding the question or what a convex polygon is. But he does say in his question that the areas aren't necessarily convex, which can also be seen from his examples. Even your example shape isn't convex, it's concave. Please revert your changes to the question and update your answer.

Comment: @Christer I typed convex, when I meant concave, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If all OP's shapes are simply composed from squares, another option is to just emit 2 triangles per square for top/bottom instead of doing ear clipping.

Comment: Yes, if the shapes were based on a grid, it would be quite easy to generate the list of squares